# How to remove values from a subset of the data frame

Tags: replace, subset

I have a large data frame.  I would like to replace values based on a subset of the data.

```
 dat <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 col2 = c(50, 100, 200, 250))
```

For col1 = A, I would like to replace any value over 75 with NA

For col1 = B, I would like to replace any value over 210 with NA

I've tried:

`if(dat$col1 == "A") {
  dat$col1 <- ifelse(dat$col1 > 75, NA, dat$col1) 
}`

I get the following warning: 
Warning messages:

```
1: In if (dat$col1 == "A") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In Ops.factor(dat$col1, 75) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message already gives you some hints. The first message tells you that the condition is asked for more than one value. That is because you are specifying the whole column. The second message tells you that it does not make sense to use a condition like `>` for factors.

The second problem arises from the way the DF is build. By adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` you avoid that col1 automatically makes factors:

```r
(dat <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), col2 = c(50, 
    100, 200, 250), stringsAsFactors = F))
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    A   50
#> 2    A  100
#> 3    B  200
#> 4    B  250
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want to use the If-sequence you have written you must index so that every row in the column is checked. That can be done so:

```
for ( i in seq_along(dat$col1)){
  dat$col1[i]<- ifelse(dat$col2[i] > 75, NA, dat$col1[i]) 
}
dat
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    A   50
#> 2 <NA>  100
#> 3 <NA>  200
#> 4 <NA>  250
```

I have change your ifelse a bit so that col2 is checked for > 75 and not col1, which contains characters.

Probably that is also not what you want. Assuming that you want to replace in **col2** all values with NA, if `col1 == "A"` and `col2 > 75` and again in **col2** all values with NA, if `col1 == "B"` and `col2 > 210` a better way to achieve what you want is :

```r
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                  col2 = c(50, 100, 200, 250),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
dat$col2 <- ifelse(dat$col1 == 'A' & dat$col2 > 75, NA, dat$col2)
dat$col2 <- ifelse(dat$col1 == 'B' & dat$col2 > 210, NA, dat$col2)
dat
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    A   50
#> 2    A   NA
#> 3    B  200
#> 4    B   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here you change **col2** according to the both conditions you wanted.
I hope, that this helps you.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: That is good. Please, accept then the answer, so that others can also profit from this.